# SpringMVC JSON unsupported type

Tags: json, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC 3.2 app that isn't accepting a JSON POST request from a browser.  If I use a tool such as CocoaRest, all is fine.  But when I use a browser or tool like chrome://restclient/content/restclient.html then I get

> HTTP Status 415 -The server refused this request because the request
>   entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the
>   requested method.

Here is my configuration:

```
@Bean
public ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean contentNegotiationManager() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty( "xml", "application/xml" );
    properties.setProperty( "json", "application/json" );
    properties.setProperty( "html", "application/html" );

    ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean contentNegotiationManager = new ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean();
    contentNegotiationManager.setFavorParameter( true );
    contentNegotiationManager.setMediaTypes( properties );
    contentNegotiationManager.setIgnoreAcceptHeader( true );

    contentNegotiationManager.setDefaultContentType( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON );

    return contentNegotiationManager;
}
```

and my pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is my controller:

```
@Transactional
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)public EmployeeDTO addEmployee(@PathVariable String officeName, @RequestBody @Valid final Employee employee,
                                   BindingResult result) {
        List<String> errors = new ArrayList<String>();
        if ( result.hasErrors() ) {
            for ( ObjectError error : result.getAllErrors() ) {
                errors.add( error.getDefaultMessage() );
            }
            throw new EmployeeSetupException( errors, "Employee could not be configured, please check your submitted values." );
        }
...
}
```

Here is my request:

```
{
  "address" : {
    "status" : null,
    "city" : "Lakewood",
    "addressId" : 1,
    "seqId" : null,
    "addressLine1" : "123 Maple Ave",
    "zip" : "80111",
    "addressLine2" : "Apt 101",
    "zipLong" : null,
    "addressLine3" : "room C ",
    "state" : "CO"

  },
  "office" : null,
  "licenseNumber" : "0987654321A",
  "scheduleId" : null,
  "user" : {
    "status" : 1,
    "userName" : "sid3@spistols.com",
    "userRole" : {
      "userRoleDescription" : "The person or entity that owns a particular practice, who has the highest level of authorization",
      "userRoleDescriptionShort" : "Practice Owner",
      "userRoleId" : 20
    }
  },
  "firstName" : "Sid",
  "ssn" : "111-22-3332",
  "specialtyId" : null,
  "lastName" : "Vicious",
  "fullName" : null
  }
```

I read some articles that say setting the header content to application/json or form will do it.  But when I set the contentType to application/json and/or application/x-www-form-urlencoded it still fails within the browser.  I have also tried submitting via jQuery but I get the same result.

if I change the controller from:

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

to

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

then I get this when I submit thru a browser:

```
Received Exception Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:123)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
```

That doesn't make sense since the Chrome rest client chrome://restclient/content/restclient.html shows a contentType of application/json for the request.

If anyone knows what might be going wrong, I would certainly appreciate the help.

Comment: Have you tried setting (in conf file): `contentNegotiationManager.setIgnoreAcceptHeader( false );`

Comment: Yes, I changed 'contentNegotiationManager.setIgnoreAcceptHeader( false )' to 'contentNegotiationManager.setIgnoreAcceptHeader( true )'  but I still get the same '415 content message'

Comment: I was suggesting it should be false (your code above has it as true) - you want it to use the accept header and not rely on file extension to detect the content type (effectively when set to true). But it sounds like you tried it with both values.

Comment: I updated my post with findings if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Two reasons:

1. Check if there is cyclic dependency (associations between entities) in your data model. If yes, remove the cyclic dependency.
2. Since your specifying @consumes in controller, make sure Content-Type header is provided in POST/PUT requests.